# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200), when trying to post on wall

Tags: php, facebook, api

I want to implement a simple posting of messages from my DB to my facebook's wall. Using php-SDK:

```
require_once 'lib/facebook.php';

$appID = 'xxx';
$secret = 'yyy';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     =>  $appID,
    'secret'    =>  $secret,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if (empty($user)) {
    header("Location: ". $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' =>  'publish_stream',
    )));
    exit();
}

$params = array(
    'message' => 'Hello, every one!',
);
$post_id = $facebook->api('/'. $user .'/feed', 'post', $params);
```

And i have "Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in ...".

If I'm not logged in, then when run this script, redirecting to the facebook login. Сonfirm the use of the data is not given.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Uncaught OAuthException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799563/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working snippet, but make sure you've downloaded the latest PHP SDK i.e. 3.0.1
If you don't have already, then download it from here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

If you go through the codes below, you'll pretty much understand what it does, so i don't think i have to explain you more?

```
<?php

// Requires Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.1: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/
require ('facebook.php');

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID',"YOUR-APP-ID");
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET',"YOUR-APP-API-SECRET");

$user = null;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser(); // Get the UID of the connected user, or 0 if the Facebook user is not connected.

if($user == 0) {

    /**
     * Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
     * assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
     * JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
     * 
     * The parameters:
     * - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
     * - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
     */

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));

    echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

} else {

    try {
            $params = array(
                'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
                'name'          =>  "This is my title",
                'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
                'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
                'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
                'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
            );

            $post = $facebook->api("/$user/feed","POST",$params);

            echo "Your post was successfully posted to UID: $user";

        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
           $result = $e->getResult();
        }

}

?>
```

Comment: BTW: This code will post a full wall post with title,caption,image,link,description and message, if you don't want full post, then simply remove everything in $params except message and it'll make a simple status update to your user.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's work! My mistake was in naming the variable in parameters: "req_perms" instead of "scope". But... post was published, but falls exeption: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later." Why?

Comment: What version of php sdk are you using?

Comment: Sorry for bumping, but why did you use echo "<script>" instead of header()?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response! Header redirect does not break out of iframe (fb's canvas page) and if you do header redirect, then it won't work. So you have to use script redirect (top.location) to break out of their canvas page and technically (top) is useful both when you're dealing with frames and when dealing with windows which have been opened by other pages.