# Facebook offline wall post not working - February breaking changes

Tags: php, facebook, offline

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, I am breaking my head for the past 48 hours on this.

**Objective:**
I am trying to post some information to my friends facebook wall through my website.
Everything was working fine before but I am getting an error now:

`Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/abcd/public_html/front_apps/controllers/src/base_facebook.php on line 1039`

Also what I am trying to do is, to post it on my friends Facebook wall when I am offline, using `cron` and to post daily by 12.00 am.

I am using PHP code here is the code:

```
<?php

$message = "Message goes here";
$link = "http://link.com/";
$picture = "http://link.com/1.jpg";
$sendTo = "my friend id";
$access_token = "access tocken";

require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'appId',
      'secret' => 'secret_ID',
    )); <br>

$attachment = array('message' => $message, 'link' => $link, 'picture' => $picture );
$api = "/$sendTo/feed/?access_token='.$access_token,";
$result = $facebook->api($api,'post', $attachment);

?>
```

Comment: The most likely explanation would be that your friend `hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`. Have you triple-checked that isn't the case?

Comment: make sure you are asking for `publish_stream` or `publish_actions` permission while user authorizes your application

Comment: @Vijay: please gothrough this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/

Comment: @Vijay: please download the code i send you in mail and tell me if any prblm occurs. waiting.... i send you link u download from that link and check it once.

Comment: @Vijay: please gothrough this and follow the steps in that link,

http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/

Comment: @Vijay: Please post the code used to get the access token.

Comment: @Vijay: Reply something

Answer (score 0):

Since facebook deprecated Offline Acces, you have to get long lived token (valid for 60 days) and store it on your server! Here is what I'm using.

To Get the long lived token right away use server side login flow

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

//get acces token from user
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"."client_id=".$config[‘appId’]."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&client_secret=".$config[‘secret’]."&code=".$code;

$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

$token = $params['access_token']; //long live the token
```

and for posting to users wall

```
//construct the image URL
$url ="https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$event_data['path'];
$img_url = urlencode($url); //encode the URL
$text= urlencode($event_data['text']);

//post to user wall - picture and text 
$post_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_data['uid']."/photos?url=".$img_url."&message=".$text."&access_token=".$user_data['token']."&method=post";
$upload_photo = file_get_contents($post_url);
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: can you please tel of how and what is the use of `$code = $_REQUEST["code"];`

Comment: The code is given to you when the user auth the app and you are exchanging it for the long lived token

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link and follow the steps.

http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/[enter link description here](http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/)

Check the below link also,

[Uncaught OAuthException: (#200), when trying to post on wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726359/uncaught-oauthexception-200-when-trying-to-post-on-wall)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726359/uncaught-oauthexception-200-when-trying-to-post-on-wall)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726359/uncaught-oauthexception-200-when-trying-to-post-on-wall) the link which you have given is working only for the logged in user and that too to post in their own wall. but i need to post it in my friends wall even im not online. Let me know if you have any suggestions. thanks

Comment: @Vijay:Can you please post the code which is used to get the access token?